# Browse button does not work on Website

Tags: javascript, html, forms, debugging

The Browse button does not work on this Website: http://www.mca.gov.in/mcafoportal/loadUserRegistration.do?link=loadUserRegistration

To replicate the issue:

Step 1: Click "Business User" Radio button then

Step 2: select "User Role" as Director / Designated Partner.

Step 3: Now, at the bottom of the page in  "Login Details: section you will find "Digital Certificate*:" browse button.

The browse button does not work NO matter how many times i click and NO matter what browser I use it

When I view source I find the below code:

```
<input  type="button" name="SelectCert" value="Browse" class="imgButton" id="reqdstrSignature" onclick="selectCertificate();" />
 <input type="hidden" name="strSignature" value="" id="strSignature"/>
```

Can you please help with a workaround and also the reason why it does not work ?

Note: I do not owner of the website, i am just a user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Becouse the site has `js` issues. If you click on the console in the window what opens when you click on the `view source` it says:

> TypeError: document.JSignApplet is undefined

It means that in their code they have a javascript error.
There isn't any workaround or is there any, I don't recomment them.

Comment: I know that people are still able to register ... so there got to be a workaround to this error. If someone can help :)

Comment: Maybe they register with an another user category/type? As I see from the code, the button misses some parameters what's not in this form/in your browser. The best answer what you can get in this situation is what their supporters can tell you, when you contact them with the error. Don't forget to mark my answer with a green checkmark :)